# GTK Python Transparent Background for PNG Image

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3, pygtk

I am using Python and GTK 3 to overlay images onto a GStreamer video stream, and I am attempting to use the Gtk.Overlay() widget to do this. The image is a .png file with a transparent background. I am able to overlay the image just fine, but when I overlay the image it has a white square as a background rather than showing the videostream underneath.

Code Snippet:

```
    overlay = Gtk.Overlay()
    # the drawing area holds the Gstreamer video stream
    drawing_area = Gtk.DrawingArea()
    drawing_area.set_double_buffered(True)
    overlay.add(drawing_area)
    # set the drawing area as the base layer of the overlay

    pixbuf = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_file_at_scale(filename='icon.png', width=240, height=240, preserve_aspect_ratio=True)
    img = Gtk.Image.new_from_pixbuf(pixbuf)
    img.set_halign(Gtk.Align.START)
    img.set_valign(Gtk.Align.END)
    overlay.add_overlay(img)
    # overlay the image on the base layer (the video)
```

Full Code:

```
from gi.repository import Gdk, Gst, Gtk, GdkX11, GstVideo, GdkPixbuf
import signal

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)

def window_closed(widget, event, pipeline):
    widget.hide()
    pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
    Gtk.main_quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Gdk.init([])
    Gtk.init([])
    Gst.init([])
    pipeline = Gst.Pipeline()
    # configuring the pipeline code here,
    # uses nvarguscamerasrc on the Jetson Nano
    
    # Creating the window
    window = Gtk.Window()
    window.connect("delete-event", window_closed, pipeline)
    window.set_default_size(1920, 1080)
    window.set_title("Application")
    
    overlay = Gtk.Overlay()
    # the drawing area holds the Gstreamer video stream
    drawing_area = Gtk.DrawingArea()
    drawing_area.set_double_buffered(True)
    overlay.add(drawing_area)
    # set the drawing area as the base layer of the overlay

    pixbuf = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_file_at_scale(filename='icon.png', width=240, height=240, preserve_aspect_ratio=True)
    img = Gtk.Image.new_from_pixbuf(pixbuf)
    img.set_halign(Gtk.Align.START)
    img.set_valign(Gtk.Align.END)
    overlay.add_overlay(img)
    # overlay the image on the base layer (the video)

    window.add(overlay)
    window.show_all()
    window.realize()
    
    xid = drawing_area.get_window().get_xid()
    sink.set_window_handle(xid)
    # set the GStreamer video sink to the drawing area in the window
    
    Gtk.main()
```

Output:
[image: Display Output]

Thanks!

Comment: You could try something like: `pixbuf.composite(pixbuf, 0, 0, 240, 240, 0, 0, 1, 1, Gdk.INTERP_NEAREST, 0)`.

Comment: Thank you, but when I add this I get an error indicating that ```Gdk.INTERP_NEAREST``` is not in ```gi.repository.Gdk```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try setting the alpha using [this](https://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gdkpixbuf.html#method-gdkpixbuf--composite) `composite(...)` method :

```
pixbuf.composite(pixbuf, 0, 0, 240, 240, 0, 0, 1, 1, GdkPixbuf.InterpType.INTERP_NEAREST, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for expanding your reply. However, the issue is still the same: ```GdkPixbuf.InterpType.INTERP_NEAREST``` is not present in the module. Looking at the documentation you listed, I really have no idea why your first solution did not work because it seems that ```Gdk.INTERP_NEAREST``` works with the method

Comment: @cadend9 That is unusual...does adding `from gi.repository.GdkPixbuf import InterpType` and changing to `InterpType.INTERP_NEAREST` cause any errors?

Comment: @cadend9 Anyway that is not the important part, it is just an enum for the value `0`, so you could just do `pixbuf.composite((pixbuf, 0, 0, 240, 240, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0)`.

Comment: I have the same problem. The solution did not work for me.
I tried the above Full Code but the solution did not work for that either.
Any suggestion? NOTE: if the underlying object is some widget other than `drawingarea`, like a `textarea`, the icon background is transparent and you even do not need that `composite`; I tried this example and replaced the `button` with the png-image and it worked perfectly:  https://athenajc.gitbooks.io/python-gtk-3-api/content/gtk-group/gtkoverlay.html

Comment: For those who are wondering about `INTERP_NEAREST` not being in `InterpType`, what worked for me is using `GdkPixbuf.InterpType.NEAREST`. But even still, this answer doesn't seem to work.